# Is there a way to implement **kwargs behavior when calling a Python script from the command line

Tags: python

Say I have a function as follows:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
```

And then call the function like this, I get this handy little dict of all `kwargs`.

```
>>> foo(a = 5, b = 7)
{'a': 5, 'b': 7}
```

I want to do this directly to scripts I call from command line.  So entering this:

```
python script.py a = 5 b = 7
```

Would create a similar dict to the example above.  Can this be done?

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
import sys

kwargs_raw = sys.argv[1:]
kwargs = {key:val for key, val in zip(kwargs_raw[::3], kwargs_raw[1::3])}
print kwargs
```

And here's what this produces:

```
Y:\...\Python>python test.py a = 5 b = 7
{'a': '5', 'b': '7'}
```

So you may be wondering why this isn't good enough

1. Its very structured, and thus, won't work if `a` or `b` are anything other that strings, ints, or floats.
2. I have no way of determining if the user intended to have 5 be an int, string, or float

I've seen `ast.literal_eval()` around here before, but I couldn't figure out how to get that to work.  Both my attempts failed:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("a = 5")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Y:\admin\Anaconda\lib\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "Y:\admin\Anaconda\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    a = 5
```

and

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("{a:5,b:7}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Y:\admin\Anaconda\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "Y:\admin\Anaconda\lib\ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "Y:\admin\Anaconda\lib\ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "Y:\admin\Anaconda\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

If it matters, I'm using Python 2.7.6 32-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second `ast.literal_eval` call isn't working because you haven't quoted the keys of the dictionary (`a` and `b`).

Comment: why don't you pass only 1 argv which you then evaluate with eval?
`python script.py "{'a': 5, 'b': 7}"`
and then in your script you do `kwa=eval(sys.arvg[1])` ...

Comment: `eval` is a terrible idea. It will execute whatever the user writes (e.g. `python my_script.py "__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')"`). Please don't do that.

Comment: @Ernst, yeah I've seen plenty of times when ```eval``` is noted as very, very bad form

Comment: @senshin, thanks, that worked, any idea why the first one failed?

Comment: @wnnmaw `ast.literal_eval` only evaluates expressions, not statements.

Comment: is there a reason you're trying to reinvent the wheel, instead of using  a module like argparse?

Comment: @BryanOakley, mostly just curiosity and convenience

Answer (score 5):

It seems what you're *really* looking for is a way to parse command-line arguments. Take a look at the `argparse` module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Alternately, if you really want to give your arguments in dictionary-ish form, just use the `json` module:

```
import json, sys

# Run your program as:
# python my_prog.py "{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}"
# (the quotes are important)
data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: If I'm going to make the user put in args in a dict, I might as well just use ```ast.literal_eval()```, right?

Comment: No. `literal_eval` isn't a data interchange format (it can change between versions of Python, even minor ones), it's slower than JSON and it's too Python-specific. But again, JSON isn't the solution I'm recommending either: use `argparse`.

Comment: Good call to use argparse instead of reinventing the wheel and making it square in the process.